# Image flickering on hover and not resizing

Tags: css

I have an image column in a grid, and I show the image to 25px x 25px so it fits in the row nicely.

I added a hover to the images and when the mouse hovers on them there are supposed be offset from the left (which it does) and then the image is supposed to get bigger so you can see it better.

2 things are happening

1) When I hover on the image, its flickers continuously

2) Even though the image goes 100px to the left, it doesn't expand to the new size.

I have no idea why this is happening.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  LoadCatalogsGrid();
});

var myData = [{
    "RoomName": "Room 1",
    "OptionImageFile": "a"
  },
  {
    "RoomName": "Room 2",
    "OptionImageFile": "b"
  }
];

function optionGridImage(url) {
  return "<div class='imageOptionsList'><a style='text-align:center;height:25px;width:25px;' href='" +
    GetCatalogImageLocation(url) +
    "'><img  src='" +
    GetCatalogImageLocation(url) +
    "' style='height:25px;width:25px;' alt=''/></a></div>";
}

function GetCatalogImageLocation(imageName) {
  if (imageName == "a") {
    return "https://images.mentalfloss.com/sites/default/files/styles/mf_image_16x9/public/king_lead.jpg?itok=4b75-ttE&resize=1100x1100";
  } else {
    return "https://pmcvariety.files.wordpress.com/2017/08/king-of-the-hill.jpg?w=1000&h=562&crop=1";
  }
}

function LoadCatalogsGrid() {
  $("#Grid").empty();
  $("#Grid").kendoGrid({
    scrollable: true,
    selectable: "row",
    filterable: false,
    height: 700,
    columns: [{
        field: "RoomName",
        title: "Room Name",
        width: "120px",
        template: "<div >#=RoomName #</div>"
      },
      {
        field: "OptionImageFile",
        title: "Image",
        template: "#= optionGridImage(OptionImageFile) #",
        attributes: {
          style: "margin:0 auto;"
        },
        width: 50
      }
    ],
    dataSource: {
      data: myData
    },
    dataBound: function(e) {

    }
  });
}
```

```css
.imageOptionsList:hover a {
  visibility: visible;
  width: 250px !important;
  height: 325px !important;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="Grid"></div>
```

** Snippet Edit **
So now when I hover the image is no longer flickering, however when you hover over the image it moves left, and it shouldn't it should just stay in its spot and when hovered show a bigger version

Comment: My first thought (without looking into anything at all) is that the _"hit box"_ is oscillating. Would also be great if you provided [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I believe so, because the cursor goes back and forth from a pointer to a hand and the images shifts along with it. I also would have created a snippet for this but didn't know how to add the images to it properly

Comment: You just get a placeholder image off of google that is the same size and copy the link address then use that link as your src

Comment: I'll do that now because I have one part fixed and that is the flickering

Comment: @KJEK-Code use https://placeholder.com

Comment: I grabbed the links for the images and modified the code

Comment: @hungerstar thanks I'll give it a try next time I need one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  LoadCatalogsGrid();
});

var myData = [{
    "RoomName": "Room 1",
    "OptionImageFile": "a"
  },
  {
    "RoomName": "Room 2",
    "OptionImageFile": "b"
  }
];

function optionGridImage(url) {
  url = GetCatalogImageLocation(url);
  return `
    <div class="imageOptionsList">
      <a style="background-image:url(${url})" href="${url}">
        <img src="${url}" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
  `;
}

function GetCatalogImageLocation(imageName) {
  if (imageName == "a") {
    return "https://images.mentalfloss.com/sites/default/files/styles/mf_image_16x9/public/king_lead.jpg?itok=4b75-ttE&resize=1100x1100";
  } else {
    return "https://pmcvariety.files.wordpress.com/2017/08/king-of-the-hill.jpg?w=1000&h=562&crop=1";
  }
}

function LoadCatalogsGrid() {
  $("#Grid").empty();
  $("#Grid").kendoGrid({
    scrollable: true,
    selectable: "row",
    filterable: false,
    height: 700,
    columns: [{
        field: "RoomName",
        title: "Room Name",
        width: "120px",
        template: "<div >#=RoomName #</div>"
      },
      {
        field: "OptionImageFile",
        title: "Image",
        template: "#= optionGridImage(OptionImageFile) #",
        attributes: {
          style: "margin:0 auto;"
        },
        width: 50
      }
    ],
    dataSource: {
      data: myData
    },
    dataBound: function(e) {

    }
  });
}
```

```css
.k-grid td {
  overflow: visible !important
}

.imageOptionsList a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.imageOptionsList a img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s
}

.imageOptionsList a:hover {
  z-index: 1
}

.imageOptionsList a:hover img {
  width: 50vw;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="Grid"></div>
```

Comment: @Chris, happy to help.

Comment: I do have a question, the hovered image, how can I move more to the left side of the small image? I tried adding margin-left: but it wouldn't budge

Comment: @Chris, please read [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp). It provides all you need to know on CSS positioning.

Comment: Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `margin-left: 100px` line from your hover class. Also, try using transform for increasing image size. The code below will double the image size.

```
.imageOptionsList:hover img {
   visibility: visible;
   transform: scale(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got some conflicting information in your post. You mention the left offset as correct, then say it should at the end.

Below I removed the inline styles you had on the image and updated your selector to target `img` tags within `.imageOptionsList`. I've also added a transition so it doesn't do a hard snap, feel free to remove.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  LoadCatalogsGrid();
});

var myData = [{
    "RoomName": "Room 1",
    "OptionImageFile": "a"
  },
  {
    "RoomName": "Room 2",
    "OptionImageFile": "b"
  }
];

function optionGridImage(url) {
  return "<div class='imageOptionsList'><a style='text-align:center;height:25px;width:25px;' href='" +
    GetCatalogImageLocation(url) +
    "'><img  src='" +
    GetCatalogImageLocation(url) +
    "alt=''/></a></div>";
}

function GetCatalogImageLocation(imageName) {
  if (imageName == "a") {
    return "https://images.mentalfloss.com/sites/default/files/styles/mf_image_16x9/public/king_lead.jpg?itok=4b75-ttE&resize=1100x1100";
  } else {
    return "https://pmcvariety.files.wordpress.com/2017/08/king-of-the-hill.jpg?w=1000&h=562&crop=1";
  }
}

function LoadCatalogsGrid() {
  $("#Grid").empty();
  $("#Grid").kendoGrid({
    scrollable: true,
    selectable: "row",
    filterable: false,
    height: 700,
    columns: [{
        field: "RoomName",
        title: "Room Name",
        width: "120px",
        template: "<div >#=RoomName #</div>"
      },
      {
        field: "OptionImageFile",
        title: "Image",
        template: "#= optionGridImage(OptionImageFile) #",
        attributes: {
          style: "margin:0 auto;"
        },
        width: 50
      }
    ],
    dataSource: {
      data: myData
    },
    dataBound: function(e) {

    }
  });
}
```

```css
.imageOptionsList img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  transition: height 500ms ease-in-out, width 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.imageOptionsList img:hover {
  width: 250px;
  height: 325px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="Grid"></div>
```

Comment: This is close to what I am trying to do, when the image is hovered it popup in another div, so you'd see two, the small image in the row and the popup. If that makes sense.

Comment: Not a 100% clear on what you're asking. You want the thumbnail on the left and to the right of it the large version *when* the thumbnail is hovered?

Comment: My apologies... when you hover on the image, a popup of the image should appear on the left side of the image because there is no room on the rightside. So I should have rephrased my question on how to add a popup on hover

Comment: Still not clear. Is there an example you could reference? I'm still stuck on the expected behavior and what a *popup* is in this context. To me a *popup* means a modal (an element that overlays the whole page).

Comment: https://dojo.telerik.com/@ChrisW76/urekivuD, if you go there and run it an hover over an image, you will see what I mean. In that overlay/popup should hold the bigger images